# Gibt es ein Substantiv von "sporadisch"?

Tags: nominalization

Wenn etwas *attraktiv* ist, hat es *Attraktivität*, wenn es *selten* ist, hat es *Seltenheit*.

Wie wäre diese Substantivierung bei *sporadisch*?

*Sporadität*? *Sporadizität*? *Spore*? *Sporadiheit*?

Comment: Bin von der Prämisse schon nicht überzeugt, zumindest was das Verb betrifft klingt es hölzern. Zitate würdendie Frage sicherlich aufwerten. Aber trotzdemist hat die Frage Interess... Intrezit... ist die Frage doch von Interesse

Comment: _Bislang gibt es für das Verhalten des Menschen in unerwartet abgeschaltetem Rampenlicht keine psychologischen Untersuchungen, was sicher zum Teil in der Kürze und Sporadiheit solcher Ereignisse seine Begründung findet._

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass es offiziell ein Substantiv zu diesem Adjektiv gibt (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sporadisch) und würde stattdessen eine Konstellation wie "sporadisches Auftreten" verwenden.

Comment: Desch hadcht dir grad ebe ausgdachet

Comment: Zeit zwischen zwei sporadisch stattfindenden Ereignissen: *eine Sporade* (oder Sporadade?).

Comment: Zu Griechenland gehören die *Sporadischen Inseln* oder *Sporaden*. In diesem Kontext ist also *Sporade* eine Substantivierung. In anderem Kontext eher nicht; das würde kaum jemand verstehen.

Comment: Per [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=Sporadizit%C3%A4t): "Wie das Handeln so ist das Denken durch Inkohärenz, **Sporadizität** und Sprunghaftigkeit ausgezeichnet." Das ist allerdings sehr ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @vectory: Klar, ist ausgedacht; ich wollte einen Satz damit bauen und die Frage kam auf. Wenn ich schon ein Zitat gehabt hätte, hätte ich das Wort ja schon =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicht wirklich, nein, ein Substantiv von dem Wortstamm, der entweder indirekt über Französisch **sporadique** oder direkt aus Griechisch **sporadikos** entlehnt ist, wäre tatsächlich zu *Spore* zu stellen und somit grundlegend bedeutungsverschieden.

Zu Deutsch findet sich *spärlich*, das zwar zu *sparen* gestellt wird, vgl. En. *sparingly*, *to spare*, wozu *-keit* üblicherweise ein Substantiv bilden würde. Auch könnte man gleichbedeutend auf *streuen* abstellen, also *Verstreutheit*, *Streuung* im Sinne der Stochastik oder ggf. *Zerstreutheit*, falls Charakter-Eigenschaften wie Zuverlässigkeit gegenübergestellt sind.

Verwandt sind u.a. wohl *spreche sprühen, springen, sprengen*, dementsprechend auch *versprengt* (d.h. *sporadisch*). Darin finde ich ohne weiteres keine Abhilfe. Da auch dazu kein geläufiges Nomen der Art vorkommt, scheint die Spur im Sande zu veaufen.

Fr. **sporadicité** kommt *?Sporadizität* recht nahe, bzw. ähnliche Abwandlungen je nach dem aus welchem Jahrhundert man sich bedienen mag. Duden (Online) listet es nicht, was auf fehlende Verwendung hindeuteten mag, ebsenso wie *Sporadität* zwar versprengte Treffer findet, doch nicht ebenda. S. ggf. Grimms Deutsches Wörterbuch. Meinem Sprachgefühl nach wäre es dennoch vorzuziehen, schon weil kürzer, bzw. weil /ts/ << *K dem Deutschen nach mehreren Lautverschiebungen nunmehr fremd ist (*K > *h > *ch, h, kk*), wobei dasselbe über den Auslaut gesagt werden könnte, vgl. dialektalisch dem Fränkischen näher stehend *?elektrich* u.s.w. und sofort die vereinzelten Allomorphe *-ich, -ig*.

**PS:** Übrigens bin ich des Griechischen zwar nie recht herr geworden, aber - ikos erscheint mir gleichfalls wie Nomen und Adjektiv im Nominativ. Also zu Deutsch schlicht *das Sporadische*.

Comment: »Nein« ist leider die falsche Antwort, und die richtige Antwort »Sporadizität« ist zwar selten, aber keineswegs albern. Daher -1.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, mag sogar sein, dass es im Fremdwörter-Duden steht und eine gewisse Bedeutung in irgendeinem Fachjargon erfährt. Einen solchen Kontext hat der OP aber nicht erkennen lassen. Zur Umgangssprache gehört es jedenfalls nicht, denn dort wirken gekünstelte Fremdworte doch albern, sowie auch *-ieren* längst verbalhornt wird. Rigtik oser Falsch gibt's insofern nicht. Wäre es nicht sowieso unsinnig, dem Zufall der auftretenden Ereignisse eine ominöse, unsichtbare Kraft ähnlich der Elek-triz-ität zugrunde zu legen? Klar, so sporadisch wie hier elektiert wird, könnte man so denken.

Comment: Das Wort  »Sporadizität« findet man tasächlich gelegentlich, z.B. [hier](https://www.uni-due.de/imperia/md/content/tul/de_ss15_lm01_bestandsplanung.pdf). Allerdings dürfte es kaum jemand spontan einfallen, das Wort zu benutzen. Ich vermute, dass »Sporadizität« nur deshalb in (wenigen!) Texten auftaucht, weil jemand unbedingt ein Substantiv  zu »sporadischt« verwenden wollte und sich als Wortschöpfer betätigt hat.

Answer (score 1):

### Sporadizität

Es kommt zwar selten vor, dass das Wort substantiviert wird, aber wenn andere das gemacht haben, haben sie das Substantiv *»Sporadizität«* verwendet, und das wäre auch meine Wahl:

- > Der Einsatz univariabler Prognoseverfahren kann für hochwertige, für mit Obsoleszenzrisiken belastete und für schwachgängige Teile, deren Nachfrageverlauf durch eine hohe **Sporadizität** geprägt ist, theoretisch nicht begründet werden, da hier die Gefahr der Fehlschätzung und die zu erwartenden Folgekosten der daraus resultierenden Fehlsteuerungen besonders hoch sind.
  > <sub>Quelle: Buch »[Strategische Optionen für Anbieter auf Ersatzteilmärkten](https://books.google.at/books?id=e4-iBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=Sporadizit%C3%A4t&source=bl&ots=rRrf-sYPzD&sig=ACfU3U0nj3YFd5wSDQXAHWDORNzRQGmcIw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp-8TO7JvyAhUigf0HHYNbCgIQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=Sporadizit%C3%A4t&f=false)«, Schuppert u. Frieder, 1994, Springer, Seite 35</sub>
- > Bei größeren Verhältnissen und höherer **Sporadizität** (mNWD ≥ 0,5) ist es im Verhältnis zu den anderen Verfahren nur noch als mittelmäßig zu bewerten (mittlerer Ränge).
  > <sub>Quelle: Buch »[Hagener Berichte der Wirtschaftsinformatik. Band 3: Algorithmen zur Losgrößenoptimierung](https://books.google.at/books?id=7371iuC5yREC&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=Sporadizit%C3%A4t&source=bl&ots=1WP3kCRLu5&sig=ACfU3U3QfeneLTmzfLp93KmG3zozlXzk2g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp-8TO7JvyAhUigf0HHYNbCgIQ6AF6BAgXEAM#v=onepage&q=Sporadizit%C3%A4t&f=false)«, Vries u. Katzenberger, 2013, Books on Demand, Seite 101</sub>
- > Regelmäßigkeit/**Sporadizität** der Bedarfe
  > <sub>Quelle: Präsentation »[Bestandsplanung](https://www.uni-due.de/imperia/md/content/tul/de_ss15_lm01_bestandsplanung.pdf)«, Folie »Ursachen für Sicherheitsbestände«, Bernd Noche, Universität Duisburg/Essen</sub>
- > Dabei nimmt die **Sporadizität** mit zunehmendem zeitlichem, sachlichem und regionalem Differenzierungsgrad zu.
  > <sub>Quelle: Abstract einer wissenschaftliche Arbeit »[Prognose sporadischer Nachfragen](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289567942_Prognose_sporadischer_Nachfragen)«, Küsters u. Speckenbach, 2012</sub>
- > Um von einer subjektiven Bewertung zu einer objektiven Bauteilidentifikation zu kommen, müssen sowohl Artikelstammdaten (Geometrie, Material, mechanische Anforderungen etc.), dynamische Daten (Abrufverhalten, **Sporadizität** etc.), als auch qualitative Informationen wie bspw. die Kritikalität von Ersatzteilen aufbereitet und systematisch bewertet werden.
  > <sub>Quelle: Artikel im *Industriemagazin* »[3D-Druck in der industriellen Praxis – Potenziale identifizieren und ausschöpfen](https://industriemagazin.at/a/3d-druck-in-der-industriellen-praxis-potenziale-identifizieren-und-ausschoepfen)«, Karl Ott, 2019</sub>
- > Aufgrund der Verbreitung und **Sporadizität** ihres Futters sind Polarfüchse immer in Bewegung.
  > <sub>Quelle: Artikel »[Arctic Fox Facts: Tiere Der Arktis](https://www.worldmap-knowledge.com/articles/arctic-fox-facts-animals-of-the-arctic.html)« auf *worldmap-knowledge.com*</sub>
- > Auf diese Weise kann verhindert werden, dass der Benutzer aufgrund der sporadischen Geschwindigkeitssteigerung an **Sporadizität** verliert.
  > <sub>Quelle: Artikel »[Google Cloud verwendet Ethereum-Blockchain- und Chainlink-Smart-Verträge](https://de.0xzx.com/2019061514973.html)« auf *de.0xzx.com*</sub>
- > Die Ursache für die geringe Verfügbarkeit liegt in der starken **Sporadizität** der Nachfragen in den Niederlassungen.
  > <sub>Quelle: Werbebroschüre »[DISKOVER in der Praxis - Fallbeispiel:
  > HANSA-FLEX GmbH](https://www.diskover.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Fallbeispiel_Hansa-Flex.pdf)«</sub>
- > Ist eine Verteilung von einer hohen **Sporadizität** geprägt, also einer geringen Anzahl von Absätzen während einer Messperiode, ist eine Vorhersage nur sehr schlecht berechenbar.
  > <sub>Quelle: Diplomarbeit »[Optimierung des Working Capitals unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Lagerbestandes](https://diglib.tugraz.at/download.php?id=576a8abb95619&location=browse)«, Matthias Schmid, 2012, TU Graz, Seite 75</sub>

Comment: ngrams findet durchaus massenhaft weitere Vorkommen von "Sporadizität" - Allerdings auch ähnlich viele Vorkommen von "Sporadität". *Einzig richtig* ist es also nicht.